# Scanning software similar to Finereader

Tags: wine, scanner

I'm looking for a tool to scan paper with a scanner, that has more options than Simple Scan. So far, Simple Scan is the best, but it is so **lacking** in features.

In Finereader you have an option to scan a page automatically, with a **timer** for the delay while you're flipping the paper. It's a simple concept, but looks like no tool for Linux has this feature. It also has many more features that make the scanning convenient.

Finereader works in **wine**, but no one actually scans with it, only using it for OCR. I'm not sure if it is possible to make it work with hardware in wine.

Am I missing something? Is there a feature rich software for scanning on Linux?